# Can I delete part of an iMessage from OS X?

Tags: macos, messages

I would like to delete part of a message history, not all of it. I know how to do this on my iPhone and iPad, but can't find a way to do so on my computer itself.

Comment: In Messages, what happens if you control-click or right-click on an iMessage?  When I do, I get Forward..., Copy, Delete..., do you not get these options? I can select any given message and apply any one of the aforementioned actions and it acts only on what I've selected, not the entire message stream.

Comment: I don't get these options. I get View, Look Up (the word that ends up being highlighted), Search with Google, Copy, Add to Wunderlist (!), Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click or ctrl+click on a message and hit "delete".

Answer (score 0):

Click on the corner of every message you want to delete while holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> key to select multiple messages, then two-finger-click on one of the messages you selected and hit `Delete` from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Ahh...that's the difference! If I simply click within the message, I get what I just posted above. But if I make a point of clicking in the very corner of the message, I get the option to Delete. Thank you!